# Discord bot command keeps working after i delete the code, and outputs several strings which i deleted

Tags: python, loops, bots, discord

So i'm trying to create a discord bot using python and at the beginning I created a simple !ping command which should output "Pong" in the discord server just to see if things work.
Then I tried to change the output to "server"(ran the code again) and it outputs both strings "Pong", and "server". The more strings I replace Pong with, the more are displayed when using the command
This is the code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong')
```

Can someone explain, please?

Comment: Are you still running the older versions of your bot?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're running multiple instances of the bot. It's not enough just to run the bot again, you also have to close the previous instance. Just close whatever program the bot is running in (Visual Studio Code, Python Shell, CMD) and rerun the version you'd like to have running.